# Periods for Irreducible Holomorphic Symplectic Manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:\mathscr{X}\rightarrow \operatorname{Def(X)}$ be the Kuranishi family of $X$, where $X$ is an irreducible holomorphic symplectic manifold. After shrinking $\operatorname{Def}(X)$, we get that all the fibers are irreducible holomorphic symplectic manifolds, and we get a diffeomorphism $u:X\times \operatorname{Def(X)}\rightarrow \mathscr{X}$. Then for each $t\in \operatorname{Def}(X)$, we get a diffeomorphism $u_t:X\rightarrow \mathscr{X}_t$, and thus an isomorphism $u_t^*:H^2(\mathscr{X}_t,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$. We then define the period map
$$
p:\operatorname{Def}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{P}H^2(X,\mathbb{C})
$$
by $p(t)=u_t^*[\varphi_t]$, where $\varphi_t$ is the unique (up to scaling) holomorphic two form on $\mathscr{X}_t$. To what extent is this process independent of the choice of trivialization $u$?

Comment: The embedding $i_t$ of $\mathscr{X}_t$ into $\mathscr{X}$ induces an isomorphism $i_t^*: H^2(\mathscr{X},\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H^2(\mathscr{X}_t,\mathbb{C})$, and one checks that $u_t^*=i_0^*\circ (i_t^*)^{-1}$, thus it is independent of the choice of $u$.